# Zend autocompletion with PhpStorm

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpstorm

I have been trying to to my PhpStorm configured to auto complete. So far, I managed to make $this auto complete correctly in a view. However I am having problems getting it's sub classes to auto complete.

Currently I am using

```
/* @var $this \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer */
```

Example:
[image]

As you can see, $this->navigation does not contain menu(), however it does contain other method calls.

Comment: *"however it does contain other method calls"* That's because there is no point to analyze subsequent/chained method calls if previous/parent is unknown.

Comment: Do you know a way to correctly/possibly configure this?

Comment: Nope -- not using Zend Framework myself. How `navigation()` is defined? Maybe you can override it in child class via PHPDoc? One "stupid" idea is to define your own custom class anywhere in the project (will be used by IDE only) and declare such method there; then use `/* @var $this \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer|\My\Special\Class */` -- PhpStorm will sort of combine them together (if method is not found in first class it will look for it in another).

Comment: I thought of doing a custom class specifically for defining them. I am amazingly surprised no one has done this!

Comment: Maybe there is another way of doing this .. or maybe lots of ZF users simply use Zend Studio for this (where I would expect to be a better support for ZF). See if anybody else will give you a better suggestions (it's weekend now and so it's quite here). Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138746/autocompletion-for-zf2-view-helpers-in-phpstorm

Comment: I have been researching this for 2 days straight. I honestly could not find a darn thing. Zend studio isn't that good of an IDE. I have had many issues with it. Auto completion is buggy as well.

Comment: Well ... my only other suggestion for now is to create already suggested custom class (where you will define all needed/missed methods with correct for you signatures; it will be used by IDE only) but name it exactly the same as original one (same namespace etc). IDE will warn you that you have duplicate class but should still provide completion from both places -- real class + yours. No better ideas unless there would be a special plugin for ZF support.

Comment: PhpStorm devs in their [roadmap](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Development+Roadmap) claim that they experimenting on ZF2 support .. but [corresponding ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9606) does not reflect any progress yet -- maybe in v10 ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about your setup, it is about the inconsistent inline documentation of ZF.

As the example shows PhpStorm knows `$this->navigation()`, because of your `@var`. The only thing is that it doesn't know of the `menu` function.

In the [renderer (here)](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php#L58) you can see there is a hint that `navigation` is available, even if there is no such function (and returns `Zend\View\Helper\Navigation`).

In `Zend\View\Helper\Navigation` ([here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Helper/Navigation.php#L20)) you see there are no `@method`s defined and there is no function `menu`, so your IDE cannot find `menu`.

Comment: Yep! I have noticed this a bunch. What I'll do is reference $menu as a new variable with $var but then I run into the same issue again. before I know it I just have them everywhere and starts to look clustered. Amazing framework. Poor structural documentation!